# Different transform from fourier transform (and similar)

Tags: transformation, integral-transforms

The fourier transform, and somehow other transform (like laplace, wavelet) captures frequency informations about the input, the wavelet instead also capture some temporal info as well, the Laplace transform is a general version of the fourier transform, but basically is the same.

I was wondering if other than "frequence" there's some other of information that maybe I'm not aware of and can be captured by some other kind of Integral transform, something that could be used in engineering maybe? Or maybe something that is used at a more abstract level?

Comment: I've not the time for a full "answer" but it depends on the kernel of the transform, ie $T(f)(x) = \int K(x,y)f(y)\textrm{d}y$. For the Fourier transform the kernel is $K(x,y) = e^{iyx}$ and this represents a family of oscillatory functions, ie sin and cos functions of x with frequeny y. If you picked a kernel which is a different family of functions (ones which form an orthonormal set is generally good) you can "project out" other information about f(x).

Comment: @AlphaNumeric $K(x,y)$ orthonormal/unitary isn't 100% correct.  For the Fourier transform, I think the unitary-ness can be written $\int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x,y) \overline{K(y,t)} e^{-y^2/2} dy = e^{-(x-t)^2/2}$ for every $x,t$

Comment: As said by @AlphaNumeric, you have a lot of transforms depending on the kernel you choose. The interpretation of what you get after the transform can be really hard to make.Take a look at the Hermite transform (An applied example in image analysis: http://verona.fi-p.unam.mx/boris/articulos/2008/CompEEMedImagFusion.pdf)